# WebSocket JavaScript client - smartphone browser support

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, smartphone, browser-support

I'm developing a web app using webSockets for network communication, it works fine when I'm using the browser on a computer, but when I use it from a smart phone, nothing! even the server doesn't receive any connection. I've  tried [socket.io](http://socket.io/) and [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) and i get the same behavior. What can be the problem ?

Additional info:
I'm running the web app on my local Windows 7 computer using Apache as a web server, and I have NodeJS also running separately on different port than Apache. 
Accessing the web app through my smartphone using wifi lan and IP address of my computer.

The smartphone has android kitkat 4.4.2

Comment: What kinds of "mobile phone" have you tried?

Comment: lenovo vibe x2 -  android kitkat 4.4.2

Comment: It may not be supported on that version of Android. (Have you tried installing Firefox for Android?)

Comment: no, let me try it....

Comment: Take a look here -> http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets

Comment: @fredyfx I was looking at that too; it's not super-clear where 4.4.2 falls on that chart.

Comment: try with emulators, are you on Windows, Mac, Gnu/Linux ?

Comment: i'm on windows 7 (specified in the post... ) but i'm using chrome on android, not the native android browser(not even available in my version) BTW is there any way to open the dev-tools on android ?

Comment: Just found out it was not working any where else than on my local computer, having CORS issue, Cross Origin Requests... https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/641

Comment: I found this http://devtoolsecrets.com/secret/mobile-using-developer-tools-on-android.html I hope It helps